# Where to put static files in webpack development

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Where do you put static files in a webpack project. 
I have my webpack setup to where the output is going to build folder.

```
  output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../build"),
  },
```

When I'm in development mode I want to be able to fetch some json files from the build folder but when I put my json files in there its not able to fetch them.

In my app I try to fetch the json file like this.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`json/test.json`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the output section of your webpack config file add a publicPath field pointing to your build folder.

```
output: {
  publicPath: '../build/'
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Farhani Walid I tried that but I get "Cannot GET /" Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Hey me, okey lets re-discuss first why you want to access the json file using the url when you can import it into the file  where you want to fetch it in ? just to know how can we get a solution here